# Can we integrate kafka with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apache-kafka, native

How to integrate kafka with react native for chat and real time tracking of a client.

and is it possible to implement or i want to use socket io for it give me a solution

Comment: *How to integrate library X with library Y* is not considered a specific programming problem and therefore off-topic. Kafka doesn't restrict you in what client framework to use (react-native is running on the client, kafka is running on the server). Also socket.io and kafka are not even doing the same thing, so it's kind of weird to ask, if you should use one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution would be to put the Kafka cluster behind a simple REST API. Using a library like [kafka-rest](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) could be an easy way to connect your React Native app using the built in fetch function. You could go a step further and try to integrate the [kafka-rest-node](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node) client into your React Native app; a cursory overview of the repo doesn't lead to any core Node dependencies.

Another method, one which would allow for "live" updates, might consist of putting Kafka behind a web server that converts the Kafka stream into a WebSocket connection. Libraries such as [kafka-websocket](https://github.com/b/kafka-websocket) allow clients to both consume and produce, whereas a more simple library like Microsoft's [kafka-proxy-ws](https://github.com/Microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws) only allows for consuming messages.

It's worth noting that mobile clients don't always work well with streaming data, and you'd be advised to test your WebSocket-based implementation on a variety of uncertain network conditions (latency, dropped signals, etc).